# The JVM data captured by statsdprofiler or jvm profiler is it in bytes?

Tags: java, jvm

The JVM data captured by statsdprofiler or jvm profiler is it in bytes ?

For a 6 GB memory I am getting this result - 6334971904 for JVM Heapspace committed.

Comment: Why are you asking? What else could it be if not bytes?

Comment: Yes i figured it out, actually the graph i was using it was saying 6.3 gb but then i read as per IEC the java 1 GB = 1024 MB is like GiB which was new to me.